# Error with strtok Function

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

In my code i get a `unhandled expression error` when i use parse function.

In my `PopStack` function is this the right way to delete the last element of vector.

Error is:

> Unhandled exception at 0x0f463b50 (msvcr100d.dll) in Boost_Test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00345d49.

---

```
class Stack
{
public:
    Stack() {GlobalIndex=0; };
    std::vector<char*> v;
    int GlobalIndex;
    void AddStack(char* txt);
    void Parse();
    void PopStack();
    void PrintStack();

};

void Stack::Parse()
{
    char* tok;
    tok = strtok(v[GlobalIndex-1], ";");

    while(tok!=NULL)
     {
        cout<<"\nThe time value is = "<<tok<<endl;
        tok = strtok(NULL, " ");
     }
}




void Stack::AddStack(char* txt)
{

v.push_back(txt);
GlobalIndex++;

}


 void Stack::PopStack()
  {
   v.pop_back();
   GlobalIndex--;
  }

 void Stack::PrintStack()
 {
 std::cout<<v[GlobalIndex-1]<<endl;
 }


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
 int i;
 Stack s;
 s.AddStack("aaa;1.2");
 s.AddStack("bbb;1.7;");
 s.AddStack("ccc;2.2");
 s.Parse();  // This gives a unhandled expression error 
 s.PopStack(); 
 s.PrintStack();
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unhandled exception at 0x0f463b50 (msvcr100d.dll) in Boost_Test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00345d49.

Comment: `strtok()` modifies the input string, and you are passing a string literal which is not modifiable.

Comment: Do you have a good reason for creating a vector of pointers? It seems like a way to get into trouble, especially if, as Jonathan Potter pointed out, they're pointers to constants.

Comment: I thought that by creating a vector it would be easy to add and delete elements from the stack

Comment: This problem is almost trivial if you use [std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), [std::stringstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream), and [std::getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline). I recommend taking a look at them.

Comment: As a general remark, I try to not use anything from the C standard library at all. Especially when it comes to string handling. String handling in C is a pain, I always wonder will anybody still uses it in C++. In addition, string handling is something which has been solved million of times and I don't have time to do it again. Why not use a library? Boost string algorithm contains tokenizers and additional algorithms. I am sure there are myriads of other string processing libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As advised by other members i have now used c++ strings along with boost library.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <asio.hpp>
#include <regex.hpp>
#include <algorithm/string/regex.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm/string.hpp>

using namespace std;

class Stack
 {

    public:
    Stack() {GlobalIndex=0; };
    std::vector<std::string> v;
    string s;
    int GlobalIndex;
    void AddStack(std::string);
    void Parse();
    void PopStack();
    void PrintStack();

};

void Stack::Parse()
 {

   std::vector<std::string> result;
   boost::split(result,v[GlobalIndex-1],boost::is_any_of(";"));
   cout<<"\nThe boost split is = "<<result[1]<<endl;
}

void Stack::AddStack(std::string txt)
{

v.push_back(txt);
GlobalIndex++;

}

void Stack::PopStack()
{
v.pop_back();
cout<<v.size()<<endl;
GlobalIndex--;

}

void Stack::PrintStack()
{
std::cout<<v[GlobalIndex-1]<<endl;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
 {
int i;
Stack s;
s.AddStack("aaaaaa;1.2");
s.AddStack("bbbbb;1.7;");
s.AddStack("ccccc;2.2");
s.Parse();
s.PopStack();
s.PopStack();
s.PrintStack();
cin>>i;
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The end of the token found, in you case the ';', is replaced by a 0.

This write operation is done on the string literal you pass:

```
s.AddStack("aaa;1.2");
```

But the literal is not writable, basically its a 'const char *', hence the access violation.

Comment: void Stack::Parse()
       {
 char  tmp[128];
 char* tok;
 strcpy(tmp,v[GlobalIndex-1]);
 tok = strtok(tmp, ";");
  
       while(tok!=NULL)
                  {
          tok = strtok(NULL, " ");
   if( tok != NULL)
    cout<<"\nThe time value is = "<<tok<<endl;
   
                     }
             }

Comment: Changed the function by adding a temp variable.

Comment: @sumitkang And? Is it working now? Why don't you use the C++ string type? C string handling is error-prone, uncomfortable and should you not be used. You could also use a library, e.g. boost string algorithms which has tokenziers.

Comment: @jens yes it is working now but i will definitely look at the other solutions given by you for better handling of strings.